# rwd-table Font not visible in Mobile devices

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

```css
.rwd-table {

  margin: 1em 0;
  min-width: 300px;
}
.rwd-table tr, th, td{
 border: 2px solid #000000;

}
.rwd-table tr {
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.rwd-table th {
  display: none;
}
.rwd-table td {
  display: block;
}
.rwd-table td:first-child {
  padding-top: .5em;
}
.rwd-table td:last-child {
  padding-bottom: .5em;
}
.rwd-table td:before {
  content: attr(data-th) "  ";
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 13.5em;
  display: inline;
}
@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .rwd-table td:before {
    display: none;
  }
}
.rwd-table th, .rwd-table td {
  text-align: left;
}
@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .rwd-table th, .rwd-table td {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: .25em .5em;
  }
  .rwd-table th:first-child, .rwd-table td:first-child {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  .rwd-table th:last-child, .rwd-table td:last-child {
    padding-right: 0;
  }
}

body {



  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  color: #000000;
  background: #eee;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: normal;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  color: #000000 !important;
}

.rwd-table {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000000;
  border-radius: .4em;
  
}
.rwd-table tr {
  border-color: #fff;
}
.rwd-table th, .rwd-table td {
  margin: .5em 1em;
}
@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .rwd-table th, .rwd-table td {
    padding: 1em !important;
   -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); 
   -webkit-opacity: 1; 
   color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); 
   background: white;
  }
}
.rwd-table th, .rwd-table td:before {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<table class="rwd-table">
 <tr>
  <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center; color: black;"><?php the_field( 'header_note_payment' ); ?></td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
  <td  bgcolor="#A8CCC9" style="color: black;">Account Name </td>
  <td  bgcolor="" style="color: black;"><?php the_field( 'account_name' ); ?></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
  <td  bgcolor="#A8CCC9" style="color: black;">Bank Name  </td>
  <td  bgcolor="" style="color: black;"><?php the_field( 'bank_name' ); ?></td>
  </tr>

    <tr>
  <td  bgcolor="#A8CCC9" style="color: black;">Branch Code</td>
  <td  bgcolor="" style="color: black;"><?php the_field( 'branch_code' ); ?></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td  bgcolor="#A8CCC9" style="color: black;">Account No</td>
  <td  bgcolor="" style="color: black;"><?php the_field( 'account_number' ); ?></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td bgcolor="#A8CCC9" style="color: black;">IBAN</td>
  <td bgcolor="" style="color: black;"><?php the_field( 'iban' ); ?></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td bgcolor="#A8CCC9" style="color: black;">Currency</td>
  <td bgcolor="" style="color: black;"><?php the_field( 'currency' ); ?></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td bgcolor="#A8CCC9" style="color: black;">SWIFT Code</td>
  <td bgcolor="" style="color: black;"><?php the_field( 'swift_code' ); ?></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td bgcolor="#A8CCC9" style="color: black;">Bank Address</td>
  <td bgcolor="" style="color: black;"><?php the_field( 'bank_address' ); ?></td>
  </tr>

  <tr style="text-align: center; color: black;">
   <td colspan="2"><?php the_field( 'footer_note_payment' ); ?></td>
  </tr>

 </table>
```

```html
<table class="rwd-table">
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center; color: black;"><?php the_field( 'header_note_payment' ); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td  bgcolor="#A8CCC9" style="color: black;">Account Name </td>
    <td  bgcolor="" style="color: black;"><?php the_field( 'account_name' ); ?></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td  bgcolor="#A8CCC9" style="color: black;">Bank Name  </td>
    <td  bgcolor="" style="color: black;"><?php the_field( 'bank_name' ); ?></td>
    </tr>

   <tr>
    <td  bgcolor="#A8CCC9" style="color: black;">Branch Code</td>
    <td  bgcolor="" style="color: black;"><?php the_field( 'branch_code' ); ?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td  bgcolor="#A8CCC9" style="color: black;">Account No</td>
    <td  bgcolor="" style=" color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) !important;">011 650 777 003</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#A8CCC9" style="color: black;">IBAN</td>
    <td bgcolor="" style="color: black;"><?php the_field( 'iban' ); ?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#A8CCC9" style="color: black;">Currency</td>
    <td bgcolor="" style="color: black;"><?php the_field( 'currency' ); ?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#A8CCC9" style="color: black;">SWIFT Code</td>
    <td bgcolor="" style="color: black;"><?php the_field( 'swift_code' ); ?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#A8CCC9" style="color: black;">Bank Address</td>
    <td bgcolor="" style="color: black;"><?php the_field( 'bank_address' ); ?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr style="text-align: center; color: black;">
        <td colspan="2"><?php the_field( 'footer_note_payment' ); ?></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

I have added css code & html code as well, please do let me know where exactly i am going wrong. fighting with this particular line from past two days.

Tried using different css style but, everything works on the desktop screens, but in the mobile screen, only Heading gets displayed i.e. ACCOUNT NUMBER.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't it be `<?=the_field('account_number')?>` BTW, 'account no' isn't the heading - its just the previous cell, a sibling.

Comment: I have so many other fields in table, all are working properly, only this field value is not showing up.

Comment: try to put some string like "test" instead of that field returned from php. Does it get displayed on a small viewport?

Comment: Ya I tried that, it works well with big screens but in Mobile devices specially in SAFARI browser it is not showing up anything, only heading I.e ACCOUNT NUMBER is showing up.

Comment: The whole table just may not fit into a small screen and if a "overflow: hidden" property is applied to some parent (table, div etc.), that cell just doesn't get displayed. Tables are very hard in context of responsive design. It is also hard to say more based on the piece of code you provided us with.

Comment: I have added complete html code, with the changes but unable to resolve the problem.

Comment: Without knowing what media-queries you've used in CSS it's very hard to help you.

Comment: also styles and an URL/working example of what is wrong are need to check it. The table doesn't look huge so I suppose the problem is with styles.

Comment: http://www.sdes.org.sa/registration-information/
here is the URL and i have updated the snippet with the css & html code.

Comment: HELP me programmers :)

Comment: great! Now I see what is going on there. The cell is there. The cell's content - account number - isn't displayed on iphones. Why do you need those inline styles `color: black` on each cell? The only difference between account number cell and other cells is that you set color there as `color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) !important;`. Try to put `color:black` as in other cases or just remove inline styles - I tried to turn them off and everything seems to be ok.

Comment: I checked it on my iphone. The account number is not shown only in Safari. In Chrome it is shown.

Comment: Hi Man, thanks a lot it resolved my issue :) i can go for the sleep now lol